# Spring RequestMapping antmatcher ignore URL

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, angular-ui-router, saml-2.0

I have a fairly straightforward RequestMapping that forwards urls from ui-router:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/";
    }
```

This is to get everything to play nice with my SAML IDP. However, I also have a websocket I'm creating which I do *not* want to pass through here. The websocket url is of the form:

```
/ws/**
```

I've been trying to work with a regex to ignore urls that contain 'ws' in them, but I've had little luck.  I get very close, but nothing I've tried gets me quite what I want. Is there someway I can combine the first /** in my antmatcher with a regex to ignore what I want? I can write the regex no problem, I'm just not sure how to incorporate it into the antmatcher.

tldr: I need an antmatcher that matches:

/bbs/index
/mailbox
etc...

but not:

/ws/info

Comment: Regex to match any string that doesn't include "ws": `(?!.*ws).*`

Comment: I should clarify, writing the regex to not include "ws" is not the issue I'm having. I'm just not sure how to incorporate it into the first part of the antmatcher.

Comment: It is easy to just deny all `/ws/**` requests and permit all other requests with the following code snippet but i guess it is not what you desire since you should also serve ws request somehow. `antMatchers.denyAll("/ws/**").antMatchers.permitAll("/**")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a simpler solution.  Rather than trying to rework the antmatcher, I just prefixed all my ui-router state urls with 'zfgcui'.  My antmatcher now looks like:

`/zfgcui/**/{path:[^\\.]*}`

This now ignores the ws endpoint and continues to only forward ui-router endpoints.  This was far simpler and far less frustrating to implement

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to leave the antMatchers as default and try to use two different RequestMappings in which one is for `/**` and the other one is for `/ws/**`

For WS requests use something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ws/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String wsHandling(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
        // Do some other stuff
        return null;
    }
```

And for the rest of the requests use something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect(@PathVariable("path") String path) {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/";
    }
```